# Why am I getting undefined on my console?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call using fetch and promises. I want to display the city in the console. I was able to display the temperatures but for some reason the location is showing up as undefined. Please advise. Below is my code:

```js
function getWeather(woeid) {
  // You wanna pass in the API URL into the fetch method as a string
  // Moesif Orign & CORS chrome extension is used to fetch this API since we are practicing locally
  fetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${woeid}/`) // Automatically returns a promise
    .then(result => { // The fetch AJAX request will be called result
      console.log(result);
      return result.json(); // This will process the data (body:ReadableSteam). Returns a promise 
    })
    .then(data => {
      //console.log(data);
      const today = data.consolidated_weather[0];
      console.log(`Todays temperatures in ${today.title} will stay between ${today.min_temp} and ${today.max_temp}.`);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

getWeather(2487956);
getWeather(44418);
```

Comment: Where do you get `undefined`?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for not being clear. I am getting undefined at {today.title}

Comment: Actually, executing the above content, it just returns `{}`. The server connection is failing. The AJAX call is failing.

Comment: The object `data.consolidated_weather[0]` doesn't have the `title` property, that's in one of the objects in the `data.sources` array

Comment: @NickParsons The request doesn't even work in AJAX.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Just want to clarify, I am using a chrome extension called Moesif CORS which allows me to make AJAX calls locally. Thanks all!!!

Comment: @QuangP. Let me know if the solution provided works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nick [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63201020/why-am-i-getting-undefined-on-my-console/63201068#comment111759516_63201020), it looks like you need the right data option. So this code actually fixes it:

```
const todaySrc = data.sources[0];
todaySrc.title // BBC
```

Here's a Full Snippet:

```js
function getWeather(woeid) {
  // You wanna pass in the API URL into the fetch method as a string
  // Moesif Orign & CORS chrome extension is used to fetch this API since we are practicing locally
  fetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${woeid}/`) // Automatically returns a promise
    .then(result => { // The fetch AJAX request will be called result
      console.log(result);
      return result.json(); // This will process the data (body:ReadableSteam). Returns a promise 
    })
    .then(data => {
      //console.log(data);
      const today = data.consolidated_weather[0];
      const todaySrc = data.sources[0];
      console.log(`Todays temperatures in ${todaySrc.title} will stay between ${today.min_temp} and ${today.max_temp}.`);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

getWeather(2487956);
getWeather(44418);
```